# Locating a layer to download for my project

Tags: qgis, layers, scotland

I'm trying to find a layer that I can download that will allow me to show the [administrative areas of Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Scotland#/media/File:Scotland_Administrative_Map_2009.png). I've found plenty sources for downloads but can't seem to find what i'm looking for. This is purely an issue for me as I'm so new to GIS, it is absolutely mind boggling downloading government datasets.

Comment: For open data the place to ask will be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Are you looking for wards or postcode areas? Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/276238/edit) your question to include new details :)

Answer (score 1):

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk is usually my first point for UK boundary data, but you may have to download a UK-wide data set and select the Scottish ones (the LAU code will start with an S). This might be what you are looking for:

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/3dc07a60f46b4e01ab0ec8ba71c7a879_4

That is the *ultra generalized* version, ie the boundaries have had some fine detail removed. There are similar datasets with differing levels of generalisation and at different times, so browse the admin areas and get what you need.

Further inspection shows your image having a larger "Highland" region, but the geoportal data having several regions there. You might need to merge. Or maybe earlier data has "Highland".

Answer (score -1):

Check [this site from EUROSTAT](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts) with plenty of different options to choose from or [that site from the Scottish Government](http://sedsh127.sedsh.gov.uk/Atom_data/ScotGov/StatisticalUnits/SG_StatisticalUnits.atom.en.xml). Unzip and drag and drop them into the GIS of your choice to see if they contain what you are looking for.